# Automorphism of a riemann surface of genus 1

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

$f: (\Sigma; p_1, \ldots, p_n) \to (\mathbb{CP}^1; \infty)$ such that

ramification can only occur over $\infty$ or the $m$th roots of unity; and
 $f^{-1}(\infty) = \mu_1 p_1 + \cdots + \mu_n p_n$.

An automorphism of a branched cover $f: \Sigma \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ is an automorphism $g: \Sigma \to \Sigma$ such that $f \circ g = f$.

In particular, I want to count |Aut(f)| where $f$ is a degree 3 map from a genus 1 surface to $\mathbb{CP}^1$ and  $f^{-1}(\infty)=3p_1$ and $m=2$ that there are two ramification point other than infinity.
Let me also specify the ramification profile over those two points. We want the ramification to be 3 cycle. Hence all the point have same ramification profile.
I heard the Aut(f) should be a subgroup of $S_3$. I am not really clear about the concept. How would we count it?

Is the count 3?

Comment: Pick a non ramification point and look at it's fiber. There are 3 points in the fiber and any automorphism has to permute these three points.

Comment: So you mean the ramified point has no effect on the Deck transformation? It has to fix the point atleast? So that would be a finite count?

Comment: Yes it has to fix the point but that doesn't tell you anything. The tricky bit is to prove that the automorphism is determined by its permutation of the fiber of a non Ramified point.

Comment: So the automorphism of a degree $d$ map is $d! $?

Comment: It injects into the symmetric group on d letters but won't be surjective in general.

Comment: Can you please give me a reference for this fact? When it would surjective and when it would not?

Comment: This is part of the general results on covering space theory and monodromy groups. Chapter one of Hatcher explains it nicely for instance.